# View doesn't recognize class in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

As you can see in the code, I have two classes in RegistratieViewModel. When I pass my viewmodel to my view it only recognizes the class Selectie and not Reizigers? Can someone help me out?
I get the error: 'CS1061 C# does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Viewmodel

```
   public class RegistratieViewModel
   {
       public SelectieViewModel Selectie { get; set; }

       public List<ReizigersViewModel> Reizigers { get; set; }

       public RegistratieViewModel()
       {
           Reizigers = new List<ReizigersViewModel>();
       }
   }  

   public class SelectieViewModel
   {
       public SelectList VanStad { get; set; }

       public SelectList NaarStad { get; set; }

       public bool Klasse { get; set; }

       public DateTime DatumHeenReis { get; set; }

       public DateTime DatumTerugReis { get; set; }

       public int AantalReizigers { get; set; }
   }

   public class ReizigersViewModel
   {
       public string Voornaam { get; set; }

       public string Familienaam { get; set; }
   }
```

Controller

```
    // GET: Hotels/Index
    public ActionResult Index(RegistratieViewModel registratie)
    {
        stedenServices = new StedenServices();
        RegistratieViewModel registratieviewmodel = new RegistratieViewModel();
        registratieviewmodel.Selectie.VanStad = new SelectList(stedenServices.All(), "StadID", "Stad");
        registratieviewmodel.Selectie.NaarStad = new SelectList(stedenServices.All(), "StadID", "Stad");
        return View(registratieviewmodel);
    }
```

View

```
@model Treinreizen.Models.ViewModels.RegistratieViewModel

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>RegistratieViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reizigers.Voornaam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reizigers.Voornaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reizigers.Voornaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reizigers.Familienaam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reizigers.Familienaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reizigers.Familienaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `model.Reizigers` is a `List`, not a `ReizigersViewModel`.  In addition, it doesn't appear that you're adding anything to this list at any point during your Controller method.

Comment: Please post the full exception. Ironically, the portion you omitted is the most important, as it details *what* exactly is missing. In general, this is an exception raised when you call a method a type does not have. It really has nothing to do with your view model or any other classes. It's also not clear where in your code this exception is being raised from.

Comment: @user1935361 So what can I do to fix this? The purpose is that someone has to say how many travellers will come thanks to the int AantalReizigers.  When someone gives a number, fields will be added automatically "Voornaam" and "Familienaam". And the Names that will be given, will be put in the List.

Comment: @ChrisPratt This was the error: 'List<ReizigersViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Voornaam' and no extension method 'Voornaam' accepting a first argument of type 'List<ReizigersViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're referencing a property on `ReizigersViewModel` on a `List<ReizigersViewModel>`. The list doesn't have that property, only a single item of that list will. You can't create a single set of fields for an entire collection. You must iterate over the collection:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Reizigers.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Voornaam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Voornaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Voornaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Familienaam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Familienaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reizigers[i].Familienaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Note the use of the indexing syntax in the HtmlHelper expressions. Now, you're referencing a single item in the `List<ReizigersViewModel>`, i.e. `ReizigersViewModel`, instead of the whole list.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I explained in the previous comment, I'll use the input field "AantalReizigers" to give a number of travellers and then it adds automatically the number of given fields "Voornaam" and "Familienaam" thanks to "AantalReizigers". My question is now: all the output that'll be given by the user, will it be added in the List<ReizigersViewModel>?

Comment: @KevinN, Your question has been correctly answered. If you have another question the ask another question.